# How do I search for instances of a sub query string in a string field in the main table - teradata?

Tags: sql, subquery, teradata

I have a Main Table (MT) that contains a field called Wine_Variety. This is populated with data that looks like the following...

```
CUSTOMER_NUMBER|WINE_VARIETY  

1001|SHIRAZ
1002|CHARDONNAY,MERLOT
1003|MERLOT,CHARDONNAY,MALBEC
1004|MALBEC,RIESLING
```

I have developed a Sub Query (SQ) that returns values for the top five selling wines, extracted from a transaction table. This basically produces a list that looks like the following

```
VARIETY|QUANTITY

SHIRAZ|10000
CABERNET SAUVIGNON|9500
CABERNET MALBEC|8000
CHARDONNAY|7000
CHAMPAGNE|6000
```

I want to find out which customers in MT have bought wines that appear in SQ.

Looking at the above lists I would expect the query to return customers 1001 - 1003 inclusive, but not customer 1004 who hasn't purchased wines in the top five.

I thought to following would achieve this but it comes up with 0 rows

```
sel * from MT 
where MT.Wine_Variety like any 
 (
   sel search_string from
    (
      sel top 5 variety, '''%'||variety||'%''' as search_string ,sum(quantity) as total_bought 
      from some_transaction_table
      where variety is not null and variety <> ''
      group by 1,2
      order by 3 desc
    ) a
 );
```

Yet it works if I try the following...

```
sel * from MT where MT.Wine_Variety like any ('%SHIRAZ%','%CHARDONNAY%')
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to recreate sample data with minimal values for your main table and transaction table. Then give the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: Don't quote the search string: `'%'||variety||'%'`. How does your TOP query look like, hopefully it's based on `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE`. Btw, it would much easier if you got properly normalized data :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think `in` is much simpler:

```
select mt.*
from MT 
where MT.Wine_Variety in (select top 5 stt.variety
                          from some_transaction_table
                          where stt.variety is not null and stt.variety <> ''
                          group by stt.variety
                          order by sum(stt.quantity) desc
                         );
```